# Motor shield causing problems with interrupts?

Tags: interrupt, arduino-motor-shield

I am making a controller for a model railway turntable and I need to control a single DC motor and read a hall effect sensor. I have the hall effect sensor connected to pin 2 on my Uno (since 2/3 are the only pins that support interrupts) but whenever I turn the motor on it triggers the interrupt on pin 2 despite the fact that the motor PWM pin is on pin 11 and I have disconnected alternate PWM pin 3. This is with the official Arduino motor shield and an Uno.

I'm at a loss here, any ideas? I know it's not the motor triggering the hall effect sensor because I connected a resistor in place of the motor and it still happened.

Comment: How much power does the DC motor require? It sounds like if it is a reasonably sized motor, it may be drawing too much power when it is on. It is always a good idea to have motors connected up to an external power supply e.g. battery pack.

Comment: Ah forget that, just properly read your last sentence.

Comment: The motor is not actually powered from the Arduino, it's powered from an external 13.8v power supply capable of delivering 19A. (That PSU runs other things too but I can assure you it's not at capacity) I bent the "Vin" pin out of the way on the motor shield so I wouldn't run 13.8v into the Arduino, could that be causing problems?

Comment: How does the hall sensor work? Is it passive? Is it detecting something and hence triggering the interrupt? But wait, you say that it happens when you connect a resistor in place of the motor, but you originally say that the interrupt happens when you turn the motor on? Where are you connecting the other end of the resistor to, the ground pin?

Comment: The motor is connected via the "B" screw terminals on the motor shield. The PSU is connected via the "Vin" and "GND" terminals on the motor shield. When I connect the resistor, I simply connect it between the two "B" terminals, right where the motor normally is. It connects to _a_ ground pin, but not the ground pin on the Arduino headers, the one on the 13.8v external PSU. [Link to motor shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3)

Comment: Hmm hard to diagnose without seeing the setup tbh, sorry. One thing I would say is that 13.8v sounds high for the Arduino - the max is 12v as stated in the documentation with 1A limit from what I have read. I would strongly suggest you try a lower powered PSU. You may damage your board if it is connected directly, and that could also cause the problem you've stated.

Comment: actually on the motor shield the max current is 4A with an external psu

Comment: I will try it in a little bit, but if that is the problem I misunderstand how current flow works. The motor itself has a max rated current of 1a, and I have run it on a 1a fuse before and never blown the fuse. If the motor doesn't draw over 1a, won't that not damage anything? I'll try a lower amperage PSU just the same, I'm just wondering.

Comment: The screw terminals have a higher limit, but according to the shield docs, you may need to cut the Vin connect jumper on the back of the board to feed in more power

Comment: You may well be right, not sure! Just a suggestion as I can't think of anything else. Check the docs: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3

Comment: @bladepanthera,  re “13.8v sounds high for the Arduino - the max is 12v as stated in the documentation with 1A limit”, see [ArduinoBoardUno](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) at arduino.cc.  Max is 20 V, not 12.  The range 7 V to 12 V is *recommended* rather than required.  13.8 V to VIN or the power jack on an Uno  is ok as long as current draw on the Uno isn't too high. (High draw at high voltage can overheat the Uno's 5 V voltage regulator.)  If motors are wired correctly, motor board current isn't relevant to Uno current except for however many milliamps the L298 logic takes.

Comment: @jwpat7 That's what I was thinking, and since the Uno is connected via USB for data anyway I was powering the Uno and 5v stuff off USB and the motor off the 13.8v supply. I just bent the VIN pin off to the side so it didn't connect. Could this be the problem? Do I need to also bend GND pins?

Comment: @jwpat7 I stand corrected. :) I don't see why the GND pins should be making any difference if the Vin is not in use, but I'm happy to be corrected about that, too.

Comment: The motor, driver board, and Uno grounds should be star connected to a common point so no motor currents go through the wire to the Uno ground.   The  motor shield probably more or less does that.   If you have a DSO you should be able to get a picture of whatever transient voltage noise is causing the interrupt.  I'd try putting a 330 uF cap from 5V to GND on the shield in case the problem is due to high current switching on the shield, and a 10 to 100 nF cap from GND to pin 2 in case EM noise is the problem.   How fast does your interrupt need to respond?